# Normalization of Network data (clustering algorithms)

Tags: clustering, k-means

I have read in several academic articles that I can use clustering algorithms such as K-means to create clusters of network data.

I have a dataset of IDS logs and I would like to create clusters based on these features:

- IP address
- Network port

I know it's recommended to normalize these kind of features. My question is: How can I normalize features such as IP address and network port? What do you recommend?

Thanks in advance. I'm looking forward to your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Clustering make only sense if there is a notion of "distance" or grouping or hierarchical structure. What is the purpose of using IP addresses for clustering? What is the aim? 
Are you clustering based on arithmetic distance and if so what would it mean for you?

I do not see where you are trying to go with this. You need to define a notion of "similarity". In k-means the notion derives from distance in the cartesian space.

Please answer first what is "similar" to you in the space of Ip adresses and port numbers. Then I might be able to propose a metric space on which you want to operate.

Only after that, we can talk about data normalization and applying clustering.

Thanks

Comment: I would like to create groups of alerts, in which each step of a multi-step attack is a group of alerts (of IDS alerts).
Actually, I have read several articles that do this, however, they don’t explain how to normalize the data.
This academic article is an example: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0166017
Thanks. I'm looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Wow that is a crappy paper. I am surprised it got accepted. Including unique identifiers in a clustering is showing that they have no idea what they are doing...

Comment: How do you define "step"? This is important, because "step" is closest related to "your" notion of similarity. Is "step" a dimension in time? Do you group attacks based on whether they cluster in time? Your problem description is still not well formulated. How do  is the data sampled in the paper. What are the key attributes? I do not think it is only IP and port address.

Comment: For me, examples of attack steps are: port scan (i.e cluster 1) , Dos (i.e cluster 2) , run an exploit against a victim (i.e cluster 3). Currently, I am not interested in time. 
Regarding the attributes, I would like to test what are the best attributes for K-means and similar algorithms to separate attack steps. Most of the papers I have read are using IP address and network port as  attributes.
By the way, what do you recommend to do this (with out previous knowledge)? Thanks @GkhanCebs

Comment: is port scan, Dos and victim disjunct attack groups or can an an attack be a combination of all? In any case, this sounds more like a classification problem. You want to know how different attacks differentiate in the attribute space, right? The problem with clustering is, that you would need to relate it back to the attack grouping. Therefore this does not appear to be an unsupervised learning problem, rather a supervised classification problem. Try going for Support Vector Machines or Classification Trees or Classifiication Forrest whith attributes as input and attack type as output group.

Answer (score 1):

K-means and most clustering algorithms are designed to work on *continuous* variables.

Neither IP addresses, not ports, are of this kind.

Instead, you should use something informed of how the technology works. With IPs it makes sense to group them by subnet. With ports, the address some ports that are closely related (and you can see why you must not treat ports as numeric), for example 80 and 443 are the standard ports of http and https, so they are related.

Comment: I understand. However that confuses me because there are several articles that are using attributes such as IP  address, network ports and other IP Header features.
The attributes used (Table 1) in the paper "http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~nat/Papers/reuben-cai2008.pdf" (in the first stage of the proposed system) make sense?  Thanks

Comment: Use what you have, not what someone else had. And if you reread the paper, k-means did not work (not a surprise). Actually nothing they did really worked...